# Workbooks.open returns Nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to read some data from a workbook, in order to set some values in the active worksheet.

```
Dim wbRegistro As Workbook
Dim wsRisorsaMese As Worksheet
Dim path, sRegistro As String

path = "C:\Users\Marco\Documents\sikelia\finanza agevolata\PON MISE\rendicontazione\"
sRegistro = "ORX.Y_Timesheet_Presenze_Sikelia.xlsm"
On Error Resume Next
Set wbRegistro = Workbooks(sRegistro)
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err = 0
    Set wbRegistro = Workbooks.Open(path & sRegistro)
End If
```

the `Workbooks.Open` returns `Err=0`, but the variable `wbRegistro` remains `Nothing` and the workbook is not accessable.

I guess it's simple, but I do not know hot to solve it.

TIA

Comment: Do you definitely have access to open `C:\Users\Marco\Documents\sikelia\finanza agevolata\PON MISE\rendicontazione\ORX.Y_Timesheet_Presenze_Sikelia.xlsm`

Comment: **Hint**: Declaring your variable like this: `Dim path, sRegistro As String` means `sRegistro` is of type `String` but `path` is of type `Variant`. Change to `Dim path As String, sRegistro As String` if you want to declare both as `String`. It's also advisable not to use reserved words as your variable name (i.e. `path`)

Comment: Adding to @jamheadart, is the workbook password protected?

Comment: dear @jamheadart, I have access to open it.

Comment: dear @jamheadart, I definitely have access to open it, and @Zac it is not password protected.
The code `Set wbRegistro = Workbooks(sRegistro)` works perfectly if executed when the workbook is open.

Comment: thank you @Zac, I adjusted the code accordingly, these are my declaration now:
`Dim wbRegistro As Workbook
Dim wsRisorsaMese As Worksheet
Dim sPath As String, sRegistro As String
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably got the problem: I forgot to say the code is inside a `Function`, not inside a `Sub` and there are a lot of similar issues on the net.
`Workbooks.Open` simply does not work inside a `Function`, unless someone knows something different.

Comment: Problem isn't the fact that it's a function, problem is invoking the function from a cell.

Comment: thank you @Mathieu, is there any other way to invoke a function instead from a cell?

Comment: Functions that are meant to be invoked from worksheet cells need to take inputs, compute a result, and return it. They're not allowed to alter global state and other cells. Use a macro instead.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Your explanation sounds reasonable. I wonder if you could provide the reference. I wonder what kind of disk read-writes would be disallowed in Functions. IMO, the problem is that no exception is thrown at all.

Comment: @ching https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel#:~:text=More%20Information,format%20cells%20on%20the%20spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Error 9 could only be raised here (*not* on the `Workbooks.Open` line, that would be a different error):

```
Set wbRegistro = Workbooks(sRegistro)
```

Since that's after `On Error Resume Next`, the error should normally be ignored. If execution breaks here, the problem isn't in the code, it's in your VBIDE options.

Make sure "Break on **unhandled** errors" is selected:

[image: VBE options; "General" tab, "Error Trapping" section]

Make sure you have `On Error GoTo 0` after that `End If`, otherwise "resume next" will still be effective for the remainder of the procedure scope (and you definitely don't want that).

Comment: Thank you @Mathieu, you're right! Err is 9 on `Set wbRegistro = Workbooks(sRegistro)`. After `Workbooks.Open` line, Err is 0. The real problem is that `wbRegistro` remains set to `Nothing`. I'll adjust the post accordingly.

Comment: Indeed the code being a UDF is a major piece of information that should have been in the OP....

Answer (score -1):

Any reason you use variables for it? If not, this would be an approach:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wbRegistro = Workbooks(sRegistro)
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err = 0
    Set wbRegistro = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Marco\Documents\sikelia\finanza agevolata\PON MISE\rendicontazione\ORX.Y_Timesheet_Presenze_Sikelia.xlsm")
End If
```

If it is not about the path, you might not have proper access rights.

Comment: Thank you @Phanti, I tried also with the constant string as parameter, but it doesn't work either. One reason to use the variable `sRegistro` is that it can be used in other parts of the code, e.g. as a parameter of the call `Workbooks(sRegistro)`.